# Compare Objective-C const char with NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, const-char

I was wondering if there is a simple way to compare a const char with an `NSString`, or do I have to convert the const char to an `NSString` before doing do?

I have been looking through Apple docs but struggling to find an answer to my question.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to create the NSString?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Either

```
NSString *str = @"string";
const char *myChar = "some string";
if (strcmp(myChar,  str.UTF8String))
```

or

```
[str isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:myChar]];
```

The core foundation route is also an option:

```
CFStringRef myStr = CFSTR("some chars");

bool result = CFStringCompareWithOptions(myStr, ((__bridge CFStringRef)str),CFRangeMake(0,CFStringGetLength(myStr)), kCFCompareCaseInsensitive);
```

Comment: Either you meant `strcmp` or you forgot a parameter to `strncmp`.

Comment: Looks like `if (strcmp(myChar,  str.UTF8String))` should be `if (strcmp(myChar,  str.UTF8String) == 0)` if you want to check if strings are equal. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

Answer (score 4):

Better still:

```
 [str isEqualToString: @(myChar) ];
```

This is no worse than a cast, which you're bound to need since the types are incommensurable.

Comment: Actually, this is miles better than a cast.  Only a subset of Core Foundation types can be safely cast back and forth to ObjC objects

Comment: CodaFi: since I suspected that the original poster came from a C/C++ background, I meant "no worse than a legitimate and safe cast", which is still deprecated but tolerated. (ObjC custom is far more tolerant of casting, because run-time support is better)

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two different things, so you have to convert one to the other. Which way you convert is up to you.